# Google Analytics Pixel doen't work in email

Tags: email, pixel

I have some email message with pixel

```
   <img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-50173334-3&t=event&cn=test_campaign&cs=email&ec=hellga&ea=open" width=1 height=1 >
```

This pixel working in browser and sending event data to google analytics correct.

But if i put code to my email template in Mailchimp and send to any email accounts(gmail,outlook,yandex), pixel didn't sent events data .

I tried another way for:

```
    <style>
* [summary=pixel-gmail]:not(.pixel-gmail){
  background-image: url(http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-50173334-3&t=event&cn=test_campaign&cs=email&ec=hellga&ea=open);}
</style>
 <div class="pixel-gmail" summary="pixel-gmail"></div>
```

But it too did not work

Maybe who know how it really work in email?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 3rd-party services like SendGrid, AmazonAWS, etc. they may cut your HTML so it wouldn't work properly.

Try to send few test messages to your own mailbox and look on the email-letter content. If there would be still any problems with that - change service or talk to support so they can help you to fix your problem.